# Can't get the CalendarDatePicker in UWP behaviour right in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, win-universal-app

The UWP app is dead simple. A ViewModel with a property which is bound by a Page containing a CalendarDatePicker.

View model:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTimeOffset date;

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public DateTimeOffset Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set
        {
            date = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Page:

```
<Page
x:Class="App2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <CalendarDatePicker />
</Grid>
</Page>
```

I run this application and `CalendarDatePicker` behaves as expected. Starts up with no date selected, shows verbiage "select a date", when expanded defaults to today's date.

The moment I bind the `CalendarDatePicker` `Date` property to my vm's Date and run the app, the date defaults to April 16, 1916.

I tried making `Date` nullable, changing binding mode to `TwoWay` and numerous other things to no avail.

Has anyone experienced the same issues? How to work with this control in MVVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The moment I bind the CalendarDatePicker Date property to my vm's Date and run the app, the date defaults to April 16, 1916.

I can't know what exactly cause the problem, but it returns a `Date` which is samller than [MinDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.mindate.aspx).

> When you set the Date in code, the value is constrained by the MinDate and MaxDate properties. If Date is smaller than MinDate, the value is set to MinDate. If Date is greater than MaxDate, the value is set to MaxDate.

You may refer to [CalendarDatePicker class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.aspx) to see this, by you the `MinDate` is "April 16, 1916", by me it's now "3/15/1916 4:27:52 PM +08:00".

But I found there is a problem in your class `MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**If you check the [CalendarDatePicker.Date property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.date.aspx), you will find that `Date` is not the type of `DateTimeOffset`, its type is `Nullable<DateTimeOffset>`.**

This is how I get it work.
MainPage XAML code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="CalendarDatePickerInMVVM.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CalendarDatePickerInMVVM"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="picker" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Date="{x:Bind MainPageViewModel.Date}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txt" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.cs code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ViewModel.MainPageViewModel MainPageViewModel;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        txt.Text = picker.MinDate + "......" + picker.MaxDate;
        MainPageViewModel = new ViewModel.MainPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

And the class `MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private System.Nullable<DateTimeOffset> date;

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public System.Nullable<DateTimeOffset> Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set
        {
            date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And if you want to give a default value to your `CalendarDatePicker`, you can code it like this:

```
private System.Nullable<DateTimeOffset> date = new DateTime(2016, 3, 15);
```

Comment: Like I said in the original post, I have tried making Date nullable like so: `public DateTimeOffset? Date`. Then I bind to it: `<CalendarDatePicker Date="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}" />`. The binding is fine because when I place I breakpoint on the getter it gets hit. However when the binding is present in the xaml, I do not get the **select a date** verbiage when `Date` is null and it doesn't matter how I initialize `Date` value, the control always displays April 16, 1916.

Comment: @JoaoMilasch, OK, maybe your problem is not with binding, but somehow it must return a Date which is samller than MinDate. From your posted code, I can't know what exactly your problem is except the `Date` type should be `Nullable<DateTimeOffset>`, but please try the code in my answer, it works fine anyway. I just edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you're right, the posted code doesn't illustrate one of my attempts. I did try your code and it does work. Digging through the differences, I was surprised to see `{x:Bind}` which I didn't know exist until now instead of `{Binding}` markup from old WPF days. The moment I switch your code declaring `MainPageViewModel` as `MainPage`'s `DataContext` and use `{Binding Date}` your code (which then is almost exactly like mine) doesn't work anymore. Although I will look up the differences between both to try to understand would you know why one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: @JoaoMilasch, yeah you are right, I just tried again using Binding and DataContext, I got error too, I'm current have no idea why this happen. x:Bind is new for windows 10, but {x:Bind} executes special-purpose code, which it generates at compile-time, and {Binding} uses general-purpose runtime object inspection. I think maybe it makes some difference for initialize of `CalendarDatePicker` during compile-time. Doc of [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension).

Comment: @JoaoMilasch, from your code, I think you want to get notify when the `Date` is changed in `CalendarDatePicker`, to do this, you can also bind the event [DateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.datechanged.aspx), if you want to know how to bind a event, please refer to [Event binding and ICommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#event-binding-and-icommand).

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with CalendarDatePicker and MVVM yet but judging by what you said it sounds to me that the value of your Date property in the VM defaults to some value. Then when the binding takes place the control interprets that default value to be April 16, 1916.

Try making the Date in the VM nullable (to match the type of the property in the control) and prefilling it with a desired value to see how it behaves.

If you cant get it to work with binding in any way you can try implementing an event handler for the control in code behind (maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/el-gr/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.calendarviewdayitemchanging.aspx) handler will do) and update your VM in there

Comment: Thank you for the advice, as said in the post I did try making `Date` nullable and tried different combinations of initial values.